# Github gist api in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, github, github-api, gist

**Hi everyone!**

*Im trying to log an github`s gist api value into my console. For example i want to use this api link:*
*https://api.github.com/gists/66db7c87873b63918e5451b06df8e0f0*

*i want to log files/sas/content value using console.log()*

*How can i do this?*

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Im just a beginner and i dont know how to use this api key

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you wanted

```js
(async() => {
  const data = await (await fetch('https://api.github.com/gists/66db7c87873b63918e5451b06df8e0f0')).json()
  console.log(data.files.SAS.content)
})()
```

Comment: Thanksssss it works. can you solve this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590856/how-can-i-get-specific-value-in-object-values-node-js-from-my-code